# How do I know if Android hover acts like iOS?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css, touchstart

I know there has been a lot of work on reworking hover to be click for mobile devices ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231198/css-hover-state-on-iphone-and-android) for example).

My question is the opposite - since it seems newer Androids (at least, Samsung Galaxy Tab S) the pure-css-hover effects work. - try **[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/qrXyE/)** for example, the hovers show on Android.

```
.field-tip:hover .tip-content {
            right:-20px;
            opacity:1;
        }
```

How do I detect whether the device will do the goofy iOS tap-equals-hover so don't end up making user click three times to actually "click" using the usual workaround?

Comment: There's no hover on mobile devices. How would it detect it?

Comment: It might help if you described how "hover" works, how it is is not confused with say moving the view.

Comment: The box you see on hover in the jsfiddle linked above, does show on Android when you tap on it (tested on 2 Androids). My question is, when did this start working and how do I detect this so I don't try hover on first click?